# what's meaning of `~w(username full_name password)a`?

Tags: elixir, sigils

In [hexpm](https://github.com/hexpm/hexpm/blob/main/lib/hexpm/accounts/user.ex) project, The line `cast(%User{}, params, ~w(username full_name password)a)`.
I know it may be equal to [:username, :full_name,:password], but why?
What's the meaning of `~w` and `a`?

```
  def build(params, confirmed? \\ not Application.get_env(:hexpm, :user_confirm)) do
    cast(%User{}, params, ~w(username full_name password)a)
    |> validate_required(~w(username password)a)
    |> cast_assoc(:emails, required: true, with: &Email.changeset(&1, :first, &2, confirmed?))
    |> cast_embed(:tfa)
    |> update_change(:username, &String.downcase/1)
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 3)
    |> validate_format(:username, @username_regex)
    |> validate_format(:username, @username_reject_regex)
    |> validate_exclusion(:username, @reserved_names)
    |> unique_constraint(:username, name: "users_username_idx")
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 7)
    |> validate_confirmation(:password, message: "does not match password")
    |> update_change(:password, &Auth.gen_password/1)
  end
```

Comment: see docs: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#word-lists.  What remains unclear after reading that?

Comment: And here are the official doc for the [`~w` sigil](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_w/2)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's first time to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the docs for [`~w`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_w/2).

`~w(username full_name password)a` is just a shorthand for writing `[:username, :full_name, :password]`. It may have been inspired by Perl's [Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qw/STRING/).

- The `~w` sigil tells elixir that the space-separated items should be a list.
- the `a` modifier tells it that the items are atoms.

Considering code is read much more often than written, I personally do not use this sigil. Writing `[:username, :full_name, :password]` directly does not take much effort and avoids questions like this from both newbies that have never seen the sigil, and for old hands that don't remember the modifiers.

Comment: sigils are more useful for complicated data like dates. Just for fun, here is my implementation of sigils for the bioctal format of RFC 9226 (yes, a 1st April RFC). https://www.bortzmeyer.org/bioctal.html